# MFC Classes and C++ style casts

Tags: c++, casting, mfc

I'm wondering if I haven't fully understood C++ casts versus old C-Style cast. In MFC I have this method:

```
CWnd * GetDlgItem(UINT uResId);
```

I'm expecting that a CComboBox (or CEdit), which is [derived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12h9x0ch.aspx) from CWnd, requires this kind of cast:

```
dynamic_cast<CComboBox *>(GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO1));
// for CEdit:
dynamic_cast<CEdit *>(GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1));
```

but this operation causes a crash for using null pointer, that means that cast have failed. Using:

```
reinterpret_cast<CComboBox *>(GetDlgItem(IDC_COMBO1));
// for CEdit:
reinterpret_cast<CEdit *>(GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1));
```

fixes the problem, but I'm disappointed.
What am I missing?

Comment: You can use `static_cast` here in favor of `reinterpret_cast`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `GetDlgItem` may return a temporary `CWnd*` pointer.

If the window is a `CWnd` derived class and the window is created with `CWnd::Create(Ex)` or the window is subclassed, RTTI will work.

When the window is created by Windows (due to a dialog template) and the Window isn't subclassed by the MFC (with `DDX_Control` ow `CWnd::SubclassWindow`), `GetDlgItem` just returns a temporary `CWnd*`, with `CWnd::FromHandle`. This window handle is always of the base type `CWnd`.

If you want to check if this window is really a `Edit` control you can use `CWnd::GetClassName`. Casting to a `CEdit*` is safe and convenient because a `CEdit` control communicates with it's `HWND` counterpart just via Window messages. So this works for all basic integrated window classes.

Comment: It seems, at least from my poor english, that you and @yupengzhang gave same answer, but you came first. I appreciated also the yu's answer because of examples and code.

Comment: I have a combo member variable. Code analysis said to use the dynamic instead of static. But for this combo the returned cast is null. This does not happen with c style cast. So what’s the solution so that my cast will work no matter what? Static? Reinterpret?

Comment: What cast di you use the MFC DYNAMIC_CAST? Or MFC STATIC_CAST? Show a view code lines....

Answer (score 4):

> I'm wondering if I haven't fully understood C++ casts versus old C-Style cast. In MFC I have this method:

Probably you do understand the difference well, but MFC had been released before the RTTI in the C++ standard, having [its own support for RTTI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wzk998x.aspx), which doesn't meet *the standard way*.

So alternatively, you could use `DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST` instead as follows:

```
DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CEdit, GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1));
```

The common practice for this, however, is not to cast, but to create a member variable that represents your MFC control, using [DDX_Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z04ab59a.aspx), which you can easily accomplish by doing <kbd>Right Click</kbd>, and selecting <kbd>Add Variable...</kbd> or through [MFC Class Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748520.aspx).

**EDIT**

So I misunderstood an essential part of the OP's question about when the crash occurs. The crash is because of dereferencing `nullptr`, **the valid result** of `dynamic_cast`, not the `dynamic_cast` itself.

@xMRi answers why it crashes in detail.

Comment: "_but this operation causes a crash for using null pointer, that means that cast have failed_" is not addressed.

Comment: @zett42 `dynamic_cast` crashes sometimes on MFC, which was built when there was no `dynamic_cast`. A crash almost always comes from undefined behaviors, which is hard to dig in on SO, when the OP's development environment such as the version of Visual Studio, and OS, and also how MFC binaries were linked, is uncertain. But I'm sure it's just another undefined behavior after all.

Comment: I usually do DDX_Control, but in this case I didn't want to add a member variable because I only need the access to it in OnInitDialog.

Comment: @zett42 Btw, think of my first sentence quoted `''`. :)

Comment: @DeanSeo no, I haven't: I tend to not use MS's macros unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: The actual reason for the failed cast is explained by @xMRi. It's not because of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @zett42 Yeah, probably I misunderstood the OP's question somewhat. So apparently the crash was from dereferencing a dangling pointer, not during `dynamic_cast`. 
I thought there was a crash in the middle of `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: No, the crash comes from dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, because of the failed downcast. `GetDlgItem()` only returns a pointer to a temporary `CWnd` object. There is no `CEdit` object, so the downcast fails.

Comment: @zett42 Exactly. So `dynamic_cast` was doing fine after all.

Comment: Yes, I had no doubt about the correct behaviour of dynamic_cast, I was just wondering why.

Comment: As side note: I tried to used DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST macro:    CButton* pMFCDynCast = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CButton, GetDlgItem(IDC_CHK_K3C_COLORIFOGLIOPIENO)); and the result is still NULL, while the result is correct if I downcast a BCG item.

Answer (score 2):

```
class A {
public:
    A() {};

    virtual ~A(){}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() {};
    virtual ~B() {}
};

int main()
{

    A* a = new A();
    B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
    // b is 0
    return 0;
}
```

As in winocc.cpp

```
CWnd* CWnd::GetDlgItem(int nID) const
{
    ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));

    if (m_pCtrlCont == NULL)
        return CWnd::FromHandle(::GetDlgItem(m_hWnd, nID));
    else
        return m_pCtrlCont->GetDlgItem(nID);
}
```

and wincore.cpp

```
CWnd* PASCAL CWnd::FromHandle(HWND hWnd)
{
    CHandleMap* pMap = afxMapHWND(TRUE); //create map if not exist
    ASSERT(pMap != NULL);
    CWnd* pWnd = (CWnd*)pMap->FromHandle(hWnd);

    pWnd->AttachControlSite(pMap);

    ASSERT(pWnd == NULL || pWnd->m_hWnd == hWnd);
    return pWnd;
}
```

When CHandleMap contains the object is CWnd not a CComboBox or any other derived class type, it will not ok by using dynamic_cast to cast down.

Comment: Even if the `CWnd` is not of `CComboBox`, how is that a good enough reason for `dynamic_cast` to crash, instead of returning `nullptr`?

Comment: @DeanSeo careful: I wrote that program crashes because of *using* a nullptr, so MFC returns nullptr correctly. I didn't checked nullptr in my program because I know exactly that IDC_COMBO1 is actually a CComboBox. yupengzhang is probably right.